# Is there a way to use the same C# class in a .NET 5 and in a .NET Framework project?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, .net-5

I am working on a multi-project solution containing an ASP.NET Core web application and multiple other projects containing the model classes, business logic and so on. While all projects were originally planned to be based on .NET 5, there is one project which is still based on .NET Framework 4.7.2 because one of the SDKs it needs to use only exists for .NET Framework.

In order to communicate to this project, it implements a REST API which is then called in the other projects whenever it is required that they get data from the .NET Framework based project. The actual data is transferred by serializing it to JSON and then deserializing it again in the .NET 5 project(s) like this:

.NET Framework project:

```
[Route("api/example/{id:int}")]
public ExampleData GetExampleData(int id)
{            
    return (new ExampleDataAccessor()).GetExampleData(id); 
}
```

.NET 5 project:

```
public async Task<ExampleData> GetExampleData(int id)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ExampleData exampleData = null;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{webServiceApiUrl}/example/{id}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var response = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if(response != "Nothing found")
        {
            exampleData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleData>(response);
        }

        return exampleData;
    }
}
```

The only problem with this solution is that there seems to be no way to use the same class for serializing and for deserializing so I always have to implement an identical class (in this example the `ExampleData` class) in the .NET Framework and in the .NET 5 project. Is there an easier way to do this which doesn't require redundant code, or can I simply reference .NET 5 projects in .NET Framework projects (or vice versa) despite all the differences between those frameworks?

Comment: you can create a .net standard library and define your class and then you can use it in both kind of projects

Comment: I don't understand what your problem you are actually having is. So why is this statement true: `The only problem with this solution is that there seems to be no way to use the same class for serializing and for deserializing` ?

Comment: @RandRandom The serializing happens in a .NET Framework project and the deserializing is done in a .NET 5 based project. I currently have the classes that are being serialized defined twice, once in the .NET 5 project and once in the .NET Framework project. This adds redundancy which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @viveknuna Thanks for the suggestion! Do I need to create a .net standard 2.0 or 2.1 library to do this, or does that not matter?

Comment: 2.0 since there is no net framework that supports 2.1 as you can see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Can you code the class in the .NET Framework project and include the class source code via "Add as Link" in the .NET 5? (or vice versa?).  Then changes made to the source code of the class would be reflected in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mediate new .net standard project between both projects

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).